# Show convergence of indirectly defined series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we define
$$
\alpha_i = \frac{2\pi}{2^ib}\quad \mathrm{ for }\quad i\in \mathbb N_0\qquad h_0=\frac{1}{a^2\alpha_0^3}
$$
and
$$
h_i=a\bigg (\alpha_i(h_i+\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}h_j) \bigg)^{3/2}\quad \mathrm{ for }\quad i\in \mathbb N
$$
I'm only interested in values of the $h_i$, which are $\in \mathbb R^+$, since theses $h_i$ describe some heights in a physical problem.

My question now is if
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty{h_i}
$$
converges.
If $(h_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ converges or its suppremum is not infinity, then I would already have a proof, but I can't seem to get either of these properties. Maybe though my approach is wrong alltogether.

Since the equation for $h_i$ is obtained through trying to describe a physical process, it might not be 100% well defined, but if I obtain solutions for the $h_i$ numerically then they definitely converge to $0$. I would like to have some concret mathematical proof though.

Maybe someone has an idea or tipp, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that your definition of $h_i$ also includes $h_i$? I'm asking because if you want it to be an implicite definition, why not include it in the sum?

Comment: @Ingix yes, the $h_i$ there is correct, I just pulled it out of the sum to make it clearer. In the physical setting the $h_i$ describe some jumps along the direction of the radius of a circle, where the next jump is dependent on the accumulative height of all the jumps which came before it. $h_i$ is on both sides, since that is the equation for the $h_i$ that I get from my physical problem.